# Two positive integer with prime number

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $a, b$ be distinct positive integers. Prove that there exists a prime $p$ such that when dividing both $a$ and $b$ by $p$, the remainder of $a$ is less than the remainder of $b$.

How can i solve this?

Comment: is it true that there are primes in the interval $[b+1-a,b]$ that are not in the interval $[1,a]$?

Comment: I think what I'm saying is true

Answer (score 0):

Just pick $p$ such that $a<b<p$

Comment: What if b>a, what then?

Answer (score -2):

Just take a prime dividing $a$ but not $b$.

Comment: but that may not exist.

Comment: $a,b$ are distinct integers.

Comment: So are, for example, $4,2$.

Comment: If we assume $a < b$, then if there does not exist a prime $q$ with $q|a$, $q\not|b$, one could simply take a prime $p > \max\{a,b\}$.  It's not entirely obvious how one could remove the assumption $a < b$...